# Why are some Cygwin packages' sources ALWAYS pending?

Tags: upgrade, cygwin

Every so often I run Cygwin's `setup.exe` and click "Install" for the "All" category. However, when I change the view to show "Pending", about seventy-five packages' sources are always checked to download. I can repeat this process ten times in a row and the same sources are downloaded again and again. What's going on here?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Does it then go through to install the packages correctly?

Comment: @me_and: Well, at least there are no error codes or odd return codes listed. After the install process it goes straight to the "create shortcuts" dialog.

Comment: Wait, you click to install everything? That's probably not what you want to do: that tries to install every single package in the repository. The equivalent to `apt-get upgrade` is just to keep clicking "Next"; the installer defaults to taking updates for any packages you've already installed.

Comment: @me_and: I actually do keep all packages installed. But regardless of whether I select "Install All" or simply "Next," the same packages' sources are again offered for download the next time I run the `setup.exe`.

Comment: Odd! I'd raise it on the Cygwin mailing list; it sounds like a bug to me.